# What is this mushroom?

Tags: identification, mushrooms

This thing just <s>popped up</s> appeared near my <s>bush</s> roses.

It looks like, well...

[image]

Credit card size shown for reference -- so it's probably 10cm <s>long</s> tall and 1.5 cm wide at the <s>shaft</s> base.

Geography = Eastern US

Comment: Mushroom identification from a picture is a really bad idea as you normally need to examine a larger number of features to achieve a positive ID. Accidental poisoning by relying on simple visual cues is very possible. I think that the moderators should consider disallowing mushroom identification posts due to the potential to inadvertently kill someone.

Comment: @WilliamGrobman - we are often asked about fungal growths, but everyone, I'm sure, knows you can never be definite enough about whether a mushroom is edible without physically being able to examine it, so the question of edibility, on this site, doesn't usually arise, its more from the point of view of how dangerous they are (or not) to be in the same room with, usually in houseplant pots, or why they're there at all. Both of which matters do fall within the remit of G & L, since they are so common. This particular one is unmistakeable... and not edible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's one of the stinkhorns, and yes it does look like a phallus. Surprised you haven't mentioned the stench yet, but you may notice it shortly, especially if more arrive. Its Latin name is Mutinus elegans; they don't last long, but you may find more appearing associated with the mulch. It's not toxic, though not edible, should disappear fairly quickly, but if you don't like the look of it, or feel it may shock some people, you can snap it off at the base and dispose of it, preferably wearing gloves. More info here https://www.bbg.org/news/nastiest_mushroom_ever

Comment: Simply amazing!!!

Comment: Don't miss the time lapse video in that link

Answer (score 7):

Yes, Bamboo, I agree. Here are a couple pictures of the "elegant stinkhorn", Mutinus elegans:
[image: Mutinus elegans from Wikipedia]
from Wikipedia, 
and

[image: http://www.mushroomexpert.com/mutinus_elegans.html]

from    http://www.mushroomexpert.com/mutinus_elegans.html

Amazing isn't it?